# Multiple header dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

How to create a below DataFrame ?

[image]

I am aware of the below concept.Need help in  creating a DF of above type

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['3_Months','6_Months'],['Python','ML']])
d=([[12,45,67,56],[78,89,45,67],[45,67,89,90],[67,44,56,55]])
df = pd.DataFrame ( d ,   index=['Jony','Anil','Sunil','Rocky'], columns=header)
```

[image]

Comment: [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html)